# VBA RGB colour specification of cell

Tags: vba, rgb

I would like to change the cell colour with RGB: 212, 231, 237 and i record macro as follow:

```
Sub Macro2()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15591380
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

I wonder how `.Color = 15591380`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code for RGB is just this ;)

```
Sub Macro2()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(212, 231, 237)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks. Then what 15591380 means? How can i do Hex? Hex(#D4E7ED) wont work

Comment: i dont know about excel and hex, and that number is just an index number that excel knows for that specific colour

Comment: @vba4all yes I know it was wrong written. I changed the comment immidiately.